# JsonParseException Unexpected character (':') (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name

Tags: elasticsearch

`JsonParseException: Unexpected character (':' (code 58)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name`

**my mapping structure**

```
{
  "patientinfo": {
    "properties": {
      "address": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "patient_current_address": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "patient_old_address": {
            "type": "string"
          },
          "patient_origin_address": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The code that build the bulk request looks like this:

```
BulkRequestBuilder bulkRequest = client.prepareBulk();

XContentBuilder xb =  XContentFactory.jsonBuilder().startObject();
        xb.startObject();
        xb.field("globalId","196ad302157add3ad63cd1154e968dfa");
        xb.field("date_of_birth", new Date());
        xb.field("last_name","trying out Rehman");
        xb.field("id", "7");
        xb.field("first_name", "Anees");
        xb.startArray("address");
            xb.startObject();
            xb.field("patient_origin_address","origin");
            xb.field("patient_current_address","current");
            xb.field("patient_old_address", "old");
            xb.endObject();
        xb.endArray();
        xb.endObject();
        bulkRequest
        .add(client
                .prepareIndex(INDEX_NAME, INDEX_TYPE, "1")
                .setSource(xb));
```

Comment: Is there a question?

Comment: @Lance yeah this is my current problem

Comment: @Lance I'm learning how to create nested mapping using JAVA API and inserting a document using Bulk

Comment: But you're lacking a question.  And what you do have is hard to read.  You should format the post to make it easier to understand.

Comment: @Lance yeah you're right  Here is my mapping file which I uploaded       http://www.json-generator.com/api/json/get/cepXyYkaUO?indent=2

Comment: Where do you get that error message from? Post the complete message, including any stack trace or similar!

Comment: @AndreiStefan i get the error inside the ES server console.

Comment: And can you post the complete error?